# $y'=(1+y^2)^k\quad y(0)=0$ functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I always noticed that the graphs for $\sinh$ and $\tan$ look very similar. Then I realized it's because they solve the differential equations $$\begin{cases}y'=\sqrt{1+y^2}\\y(0) = 0\end{cases}\quad \text{and} \quad \begin{cases}y'=1+y^2\\y(0) = 0,\end{cases}$$ respectively.

Are the solutions of any other powers of $y'=1+y^2$ familiar functions?

Comment: Probably not; for $k > 1/2,$ we know $y$ blows up in finite time, we also know that bound decreases as $k$ increases. So you don't get a rational function of $\tan x,$ for example.

Comment: wait, unless some $k$ gave $\tan 2x$ or the like, that would change the vertical asymptote

Comment: @WillJagy Where may I find the proof that for $k>1/2$, $y$ blows up in finite time? I haven't read a rigorous proof of this familiar fact (just starting studying diff EQ in earnest).

Comment: Eric, working on $1/2 < k < 1;$ I don't have a reference, I just played around with differential inequalities years ago. I think $k > 1$ must exceed $\tan x.$

Comment: Eric, this is enough to give a lower bound after $y$ gets large enough, if $y' = y^{(1+\epsilon)},$ then $$ y = \left( \epsilon (C-t) \right)^{-1/\epsilon} $$

Answer (score 1):

Other than $\sinh x$ and $\tan x$, probably the only remaining familiar solution is
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},
\end{align}
which corresponds to $k = 3/2$.  This seems to be the only other $k>0$ for which $y$ can be stated as an explicit function of $x$ in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks. What was your method to come up with this? Just trial and error?

Comment: Just trial and error.  After $k = 1/2$ and $k = 1$, I figured a logical one to try is $k = 3/2$.  Luckily the implicit solution can be easily inverted.